# how to get textbox value into label using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I get the value of textbox into label when I click on a button using jquery.

I know how to write the click event in jquery. But when I write something like

```
$('#labelID').val() = $('#textboxID').val();
```

I get an error saying 'cannot assign to a function result'

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#labelID').html ( $('#textboxID').val() );
```

val/html methods in jQuery act as getters and as setters. If you pass a value to them then they will set the value/html of the element to the passed value. If you just call val() you will get the value of the element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#labelID').html($('#textboxID').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var value = $("#textbox1").val();
                $("#label1").html(value);
                return false;
```