# When to use jQuery .html or .text on an element

Tags: jquery, performance

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501592/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-label-into-a-textbox-with-jquery) that I posted (and was answered), I found out how to properly assign the value of a textbox to the value of a label. The answer was to use either

```
$('#txtBranchName').val($('#lblBranchName').html());
```

or

```
$('#txtBranchName').val($('#lblBranchName').text());
```

Is one preferable over the other? Are there performance differences, or would one method not work but the other would in particular situations?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-text-and-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Refer** : [What is the difference between jQuery: text() and html() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910794/jquery-text-vs-html)  and [Differences between .text() and .html() with escaped < and > characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459992/differences-between-text-and-html-with-escaped-and-characters)

Actually both do look somewhat similar but are quite different it depends on your usage or intention what you want to achieve ,

Where to use:

- use .html() to operate on containers having html elements.
- use .text() to modify text of elements usually having separate open and closing tags

`jQuery.html()` treats the string as HTML, `jQuery.text()` treats the content as text.

> Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML
>   documents. The result of the .text() method is a string containing the
>   combined text of all matched elements. (Due to variations in the HTML
>   parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines
>   and other white space.)

Answer (score 20):

### Setting data

`.text("<b>Test</b>")` will escape any HTML tags (rendering `<b>Test</b>`)

`.html("<b>Test</b>")` will render them as actual HTML elements (rendering **Test**).

### Reading data

`.text()` will return text nodes only (stripping tags)

`.html()` will return actual HTML string including tags.

---

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N25jw/) that shows the difference both ways.

Comment: It doesn't escape them, it ignores them.

Comment: @Kolink: Yes when reading values. I've updated my answer to include info both ways.

Comment: It does not render them as text. It extracts only text from html tags without styles..

Comment: @Exception: I've said that when reading data `.text` only returns text nodes. Check my linked fiddle and you'll see what it does. Writing and reading.

Answer (score 5):

If there are no HTML children of the label, then it's the same either way, however if there are any (such as a red "required" mark) it would be preferably to use `.text()` so you just get that mark rather than the HTML generating it.